# Rails 3 Routing: non-CRUD controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need a bit of help with converting routing from Rails 2 to Rails 3.

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, I have:

```
<%= link_to "Reports", reports_path %><br>
```

There is a `ReportsController`, and in `app/views/reports/index.html.erb`, I have this:

```
<%= link_to "Clients With Animals", :action => "getAnimals", :controller => "clients" %>
```

Then, in config/routes.rb, I have this (Rails 3)

```
match '/reports' => "reports#index"
match '/clients/getAnimals', to: "clients#getAnimals"
```

I get this error when I click on the "getAnimals" link on the reports page:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClientsController#show
Couldn't find Client with id=getAnimals
```

I don't want "getAnimals" to be the ID - I want it to be the action, instead.

How do I do that?

Comment: What *else* do you have in `routes.rb`? Do you have something *before* the `/clients/getAnimals` match that would match the URL? Like a client resource, or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you also have a `resources :clients` entry, you want to make sure `match '/clients/getAnimals', to: "clients#getAnimals"` is above it (Rails will match whatever it hits first).

However, the better way may be to put it in the resource:

```
resources :clients do
  get 'getAnimals', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: @dave_newton and Dylan, thanks so much. Dave's question was totally germane - there was resources :clients above the '/clients/getAnimals', so it was matching that. Both of Dylan's suggestions work - and I'm using the second one, to put it in the resource. Thanks so much, for answering so quickly.

Comment: I have one other question related to this. In Rails 2, you could do this - map.connect '/reports', :controller => "reports" and it would send any action (like getAnimals) to the reports index. In Rails 3, is there a way to do it generically, or do I have to list each specific action under resources :clients?

Comment: You could do something like `match 'reports(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' => 'reports'`, which would allow things like `/reports/getAnimals` and `/reports/forAnimal/40`, etc.

Comment: Dylan, thanks again. With that approach, I get an error which very much confused me, "No route matches [GET] assets". I did some reading about the "assets pipeline," and it seemed that if you didn't put something in the resource, you wouldn't get the assets. Your solution, from earlier (involving putting it in the clients resource) gets rid of the assets error. I suspect I do not understand Rails 3 routing well enough. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.